# Recuperar e calcular valores de EditText gerada programaticamente

Tags: java, android, edittext

Eu estou criando um app pqra calcular uma média aritmética de N valores. Existe um botão *add*, quando for clicado ele vai gerar um `EditText` programaticamente. E vai ter um botão calcular, quando ele for clicado, deve mostrar a media das `EditText` criadas.

Porém não estou conseguindo recuperar os valores dessas `EditText` pra usar no botão calcular. Abaixo está meu código java:

```
private ArrayList<EditText> listEdit = new ArrayList<>();
botaoAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aviso.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container); //criar o container(pai)
            listEdit.add(new EditText(getActivity()));
            listEdit.get(count).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            listEdit.get(count).setHint("Media " + count);
            listEdit.get(count).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            listEdit.get(count).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,100); // tamanho do container
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,15,0,0);
            layout.addView(listEdit.get(count),layoutParams); //adicionando a view ao container
            count++;
        }
    });

botaoCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i =0; i < listEdit.size(); i++){
                String texto = listEdit.get(i).getText().toString();
                if(!texto.isEmpty()){
                    Double valor = Double.parseDouble(texto);
                    Double result = 0.0;
                    result = result + valor;
                    Double media = result/(i+1);
                    resultado.setText("media " + media);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Como eu li em outros posts aqui, recomendaram sempre guardar os valores das `EditText` em uma `ArrayList` para usar ela. O problema desse código é que ele não esta somando os valores, ele apenas está pegando o valor da última `EditText` e dividindo pelo número de `EditText`s (no caso, o `i` do `for`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A média tem que ser calculada fora do laço:

```
Double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < listEdit.size(); i++) {
  String texto = listEdit.get(i).getText().toString();
  if (!texto.isEmpty()) {
    total += Double.parseDouble(texto);
  }
}
Double media = total / listEdit.size();
resultado.setText("media " + media);
```

Comment: Ahhh, eu alterei tanta coisa, usei chieldCont, e nao reparei nesse detalhe. Deu certo aqui, vlw :D

Comment: O único detalhe é que nesse caso usar `double` (o tipo primitivo) ao invés de `Double` (a classe empacotadora) é mais eficiente porque evita autoboxes e autounboxes desnecessários.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<EditText> colecaoEditText = newArrayList<EditText>();
int vezesClicados = 0;

addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(...){
    EditText editText = new EditText(MinhaActivity.this);

    meuContainer.addChild(editText);
    colecaoEditText.add(editText);
    vezesClicados++;
});// Pode adicionar quantos quiser e ele estará no ArrayList

//vamos pegar o valor de todos com um loop (abaixo)
for(int i = 0; i <= vezesClicados; i++){
    //aqui você pega o valor dos editTexts pelo índice dele no array e faz o que quiser
    colecaoEditText.get(i).getText().toString(); //aqui eu só mostrei como vc pegaria o texto do editText
}
```

Comment: Hm, deu certo dessa maneira tbm, vlw :D

Comment: Com grandes poderes vem grandes responsabilidades em, hahaha, passe adiante